# httpd (pid 1766) already running but I can't load localhost and see apache confirmation on browser

Tags: linux, apache, centos, apache-config

so I installed APACHE on linux ..and I typed apachectl start and get httpd (pid 1766) already running  but I can't see nothing on the browser .. When I type the local IP address of the machine, It's supposed to bring a screen with APACHE to show that it's running now ..but page keeps loading and loading ..

Answer (score 5):

There're a problem with config.

- First try restart (if pid already running... first stop)
  Another question help you
- Open httpd.conf, looking httpd.pid (or apache.pid or chain. "Pid") for the location
- ps aux |grep httpd # you see process of apache running. If running stop it. Check the settings
- On system ls -lisa "location_of_pid"
- If any result, remove file "location_of_pid"